# Does nginx have a soft quit?

Tags: nginx

Does anyone know if nginx supports soft quits?  Meaning does it stay running until all connections are either gone or timed out (past a specific time interval) and also not allow new connections during this time period?

For example:

```
nginx stop
nginx running (2 connections active and blocking any new connections)
nginx running (1 connection active)
nginx stopped (0 connections active)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**man nginx**

```
 -s signal      Send signal to the master process. The argument signal can be
                one of: stop, quit, reopen, reload.

                The following table shows the corresponding system signals.

                stop    SIGTERM
                quit    SIGQUIT
                reopen  SIGUSR1
                reload  SIGHUP
```

Specifically, you want SIGQUIT. In layperson's terms:

- `stop` — fast shutdown
- `quit` — graceful shutdown
- `reload` — reloading the configuration file
- `reopen` — reopening the log files

See also: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html for details, and http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control for a quick reference.